# not seeing node list when using console.log

Tags: javascript, iife

I am still learning javascript, I found this code as part of a tutorial and do not understand why I can console.log the `el` variable and see a collection. With the `tabNavigationLinks` variable, there is an empty collection of items.  Help in understanding what I am missing in this section of javascript.

Thanks

```
   (function() {

      'use strict';

      var tabs = function(options) {

        var el = document.querySelector(options.el);
        var tabNavigationLinks = el.querySelectorAll(options.tabNavigationLinks);

         console.log(tabNavigationLinks);  // empty list of items

        var tabContentContainers = el.querySelectorAll(options.tabContentContainers);
        var activeIndex = 0;
        var initCalled = false;

      };

  window.tabs = tabs;

})();
```

Html

```
<div id="tabs" class="c-tabs no-js">
      <div class="c-tabs-nav">
        <a href="#" class="c-tabs-nav__link is-active"></a>
        <a href="#" class="c-tabs-nav__link"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="c-tab is-active">
        <div class="c-tab__content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="c-tab">
      <div class="c-tab__content"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Object passed into options varialbe

```
 var myTabs = tabs({
el: '#tabs',
tabNavigationLinks: '.c-tabs-nav__link',
tabContentContainers: '.c-tab'
```

});

Comment: Think we need some more of the snippet from the example.  `options` could simply not have that property defined.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to show us how and when you call `tabs`, especially what the `options` are. Given that those are different selectors, getting different results doesn't seem unexpected.

Comment: Where exactly are you logging `el`, and what do you see? Doesn't look like it would be a collection.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector()` will either return a "node" or `null`, depending on whether it can find an element that matches the selector you provide. In your sample, you have this:

```
 var el = document.querySelector(options.el);
```

which should return `null` because there are no quotes around `options.el`, which means that `options.el` would be evaluated as the `el` property of the `options` object. When a query like this returns `null`, you do not get an error immediately. Instead, when you go to use the variable that was supposed to store the result, you get the `null` or if you try to access a property of the object, you get a `null` exception.

I think you meant to write:

```
 var el = document.querySelector("options.el");
```

Because that is a valid selector (all the `options` elements that have the `el` class. However, there is not `options` (plural) element in HTML.

`document.querySelectorAll()` will return a "node list" - - always. Whether the node list contains anything all depends on how many elements were found that match the supplied query. When you write:

```
 el.querySelectorAll(options.tabNavigationLinks);
```

You will get a node list that contains all the `options` elements that have the `tabNavigationLinks` class or you will get an empty node list. But again, there is no `options` (plural) element in HTML.

To be able to tell you more, we need to see your HTML.